# EF Core - how to re-generate a migration

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

When using EF Core I can create a migration using the following command:

```
Add-Migration Foo
```

Now I would like to make some changes to the data model and update the `Foo` migration accordingly. Currently I need to do that in two steps.

```
Remove-Migration; Add-Migration Foo
```

Is there any command which will remove and re-add the migration in one step? Something like

```
Update-Migration Foo
```

or something equivalent to `-Force` parameter in EF6?

Answer (score 0):

There is no command for this, And one more thing that you don't remove migration `Foo`and create it again. Instead of doing this you create a new migration for new changes. because it will be easy for you to track these new changes in the future. you can easily find that you modify these changes in this particular migration.

Comment: That's not necessarily easier, especially if you simply missed adding a property or piece of configuration to what should have been in the previous migration. There will be times that your workflow is correct, but also times that the OPs is the correct approach.